# Python - Dictionary duplicate values

Tags: python-2.7

I have the below dictionary and I attempted to remove duplicates using the below piece of code.

```
vertex = {1: (4.0,7.0), 2: (1.0,4.0), 3: (5.0,8.0), 4: (5.0,6.0), 5: (3.0,8.0), 6: (4.0,7.0), 7: (1.0,4.0), 8: (5.0,8.0), 9: (4.0,2.0), 10: (4.0,8.0), 11: (4.0,7.0), 12: (4.0,2.0), 13: (4.0,8.0), 14: (1.0,4.0), 15: (5.0,8.0), 16: (4.0,4.0), 17: (4.0,2.0), 18: (4.0,8.0), 19: (2.0,2.0), 20: (5.0,5.0), 21: (4.0,7.0), 22: (4.0,2.0), 23: (4.0,8.0), 24: (5.0,6.0), 25: (3.0,8.0)}

 result = {}
 for key,value in vertex.items():
     if value not in result.values():
                result[key] = value
 print result
```

The duplicate values are still getting added to result.

```
[] (4.0,7.0)  - initial result and value to be checked if its already in result

[(4.0,7.0)] (1.0,4.0)

[(4.0,7.0), (1.0,4.0)] (5.0,8.0)

[(4.0,7.0), (1.0,4.0), (5.0,8.0)] (5.0,6.0)

[(4.0,7.0), (1.0,4.0), (5.0,8.0), (5.0,6.0)] (3.0,8.0)

[(4.0,7.0), (1.0,4.0), (5.0,8.0), (5.0,6.0), (3.0,8.0)] (4.0,7.0) - here (4.0,7.0) is being checked and its getting added though it is already there in it as shown in next step.


[(4.0,7.0), (1.0,4.0), (5.0,8.0), (5.0,6.0), (3.0,8.0), (4.0,7.0)] (1.0,4.0)
```

Can anyone tell me where exactly it goes wrong? I am unable to figure that out!
Thanks.

Comment: I ran the same code you have posted and it seemed to work for me. Here is my output `{1: (4.0, 7.0), 2: (1.0, 4.0), 3: (5.0, 8.0), 4: (5.0, 6.0), 5: (3.0, 8.0), 9: (4.0, 2.0), 10: (4.0, 8.0), 16: (4.0, 4.0), 19: (2.0, 2.0), 20: (5.0, 5.0)}` Double check your indentation

Comment: Note that this is expected to be non-deterministic. The iteration order for dictionaries is not guaranteed. If you don't care, double-inverting the dictionary is probably faster.

Comment: So when I try giving the input manually and checking as a separate code, it works fine. While its executed as a part of another program comparison of equal elements in dictionary/list end up like they are not equal. I'm missing something somewhere. Still trying to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @dhke order of iteration does not required in my case. Anyway I will have this in mind for future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with unique tuples, set() can perform better in this case. Try this:

```
vertex_set = set()
results = {}
for key, value in vertex.items():
    if not value in vertex_set:
        result[key] = value
        vertex_set.add(value)
```

For more on sets, refer https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html